# Next.js: getInitialProps not working with history (back button)

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have an app with a single page `index.js`, and I parse the query parameters in `getInitialProps`:

```
static async getInitialProps ({query}) {
    console.log('PAGE', query.screenId);
    try {
        const projectData = await ProjectLoader.loadProject(query);
        return projectData;
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
};
```

I use `<Link href={pathname, query} prefetch>` tags to build my links.

The `screenId` property is key to finding the right page to render.

However, when I use the back button in the browser to a page without `screenId` set, `getInitialProps` doesn’t return `screenId:undefined` as expected, but another value (as you can see in the console log):

[image: getInitialProps not working with history]

When I refresh the page, I get the right properties and see the correct results.

The “imaginary” `screenId` is actually a valid value, but I have no idea where this value comes from.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Probably unrelated but it should be `<Link to={pathname, query} prefetch>`

Comment: @Daniel Thanks, this is Next.js own router, not react-router - different syntax? https://github.com/zeit/next.js#with-url-object

Comment: Sorry, thought you were using React-Router

Comment: hi @TomSöderlund have you found a solution to this?

Comment: @Kenshinman Nope not yet – you have the same issue?